# Why does List<IShape>.Sort() call CompareTo(Object) rather than CompareTo(Shape)?

Tags: c#, sorting, contravariance, compareto

Earlier, I was provided a concrete example of contravariance in the generic `IComparable<T>` interface by Jon Skeet. This has, however, spawned yet another question. Why isn't the generic `List<T>.Sort()` method able to infer the same information?

I've provided the referenced example here as the `static Foo<T>()` method. You'll observe that this method is able to infer the type of `T` and call `CompareTo(Circle)`. `List<ICircle>.Sort()` on the other hand is unable to infer the type of `T` and so calls `CompareTo(Object)`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Testable
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<ICircle> circles = new List<ICircle>();

            circles.Add(new Circle());
            circles.Add(new Circle());

            circles.Sort();

            Foo(new Circle(), new Circle());
        }

        public static void Foo<T>(IComparable<T> a, T b) where T : ICircle
        {
            a.CompareTo(b);
        }
    }

    public interface ICircle
    {
    }

    public class Circle :
    IComparable, IComparable<Circle>, ICircle
    {
        public Int32 CompareTo(Object other)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called CompareTo(Object)");
            return 0;
        }

        public Int32 CompareTo(Circle other)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called CompareTo(Circle)");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is a list of `ICircle`, not a list of `Circle`.  `ICircle` doesn't implement `IComparable<Circle>` or `IComparable<ICircle>` (or any other `IComparable` interface.  All of the items that you put into the list do happen to implement `IComparer<Circle>` and be `Circle`s, but you could just as easily put an item in that implemented `ICircle` and implemented no `IComparable` interfaces at all.

`Foo` on the other hand takes an `IComparable<T>` as a parameter, so you *know* that it implements `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Servy, seems like List<T>.Sort() takes an IComparable/IComparable<T> behind the scenes as well. Hm, I'm now wondering if this has to do with the fact that the where clause is a restriction rather than a required type. Which means that the example may not actually demonstrate contravariance.